# How to communicate between electron app and opened other browser?

Tags: python, vue.js, electron

I want to communicate between electron app and opened other brower. I have to send params from electron to other browser or from browser to electron app. But there is no way.
please help me!

Comment: Why don't you just create an API for that? given that your application requires a user to log-in, you can send data from app to browser and vise versa by sending it to your backend which will relay the data to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem very realistic. But I have a few ideas here:

Electron -> Browser

- Webserver which you can open in the Browser
- write a Browser extension

Browser -> Electron

- A special url like the ones apple uses for the app store (e.g.: itmss://itunes.apple.com/de/store?...)

Due to security reasons it is not possible to "talk" to a browser and access other webpages information. Otherwise it would be easy to leak cookies and personal data.

Comment: Actually you can, by spawning a local web/socket server in a specific port from his electron app which can then be accessed in his page that is opened in the browser.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag: you should rather explain your solution in an answer, instead of leaving it as a comment of another answer.